# How to make y-axis labels center-aligned in seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I generate two plots in seaborn which share y-axis. I'm wondering how I can make the shared y-axis labels center-aligned. I am looking for some ideas and improvements. The plot is attached. [image]

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import string
import random

labels = []

for i in range(10):
   labels.append(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=4)))
   labels.append(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=7)))     
   
score = np.abs(np.random.randn(20))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2 , figsize=(5,5 ),  sharey=True )

for ii in range(2):   
    ti = sns.barplot(y=[j for j in range(len(score))],x=score, ax=axes[ii],                         
                      orient='h' )    
    ti.set_yticklabels(labels)            
    if ii ==0:
         ti.invert_xaxis()
         ti.yaxis.tick_right()      
            
fig.tight_layout(w_pad=0, pad=1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you also possible attach the current image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ti.set_yticklabels(labels)` has options to align horizontally using `ha`, multi-align text with `ma`. I have made use of ha and adjusted using the `position` argument as well. It seems to be aligned. Probably this could also help to design and play with it to get to right format. [Reference here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels.html) (Look at other parameters)

Below is the updated code snippet for the part of the changes only:

```
for ii in range(2):   
    ti = sns.barplot(y=[j for j in range(len(score))],x=score, ax=axes[ii],                         
                      orient='h')    
    ti.set_yticklabels(labels, ha="center", position=(1.2,0)) # ha and position adjustments.           
    if ii ==0:
         ti.invert_xaxis()
         ti.yaxis.tick_right()     
            
plt.tight_layout(w_pad=0, pad=2.5) # Some padding adjustments.
plt.show()
```

Finally the output looks like this:
[image]